# TeX4ht: can we prevent italic capital greek letters in mathml or mathml,mathjax output

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, mathml

I am trying to convert document to HTML with MathML rendered by MathJax (the reason is that pure mathjax output does not do proper equation numbering). Unfortunately, I get all the capital greek letters in formulas in italic font, while they clearly should be upright (as formatted by normal TeX).

That is, the test document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \Psi+\psi=P+p
\]
\end{document}
```

which is compiled with

```
make4ht -u test 'html,mathml,mathjax'
```

Gives the output that looks like

[image]

While I would clearly prefer the original LaTeX formatting

[image]

As for now, I can get the proper formula in two cases:

```
make4ht -u test 'html'
```

which inserts PNG image of the formula -- not at all what I would like to look nice on screen. Other way

```
make4ht -u test 'html,mathjax'
```

This one looks nice (proper resolution/browser independent formatting by MathJax), but fails on documents with equation numbering.

I would be glad to have suggestions!

Comment: Correction taken. By 'proper MathJax' I meant that it looks nice on screen :) Rendered in a resolution and browser independent way by MathJax. The problem here is that MathJax does not have a very good way to render the equation numbers. Actually, it has, but tex4ht with 'mathjax' output format fails to feed mathjax the equation numbers in a proper way, while 'mathml,mathjax' formats the equation numbers correctly. Probably, fixing the mathjax.4ht to deal with equation numbers using mathjax `tagformat` is the best solution, but my fisrt hope was to evade coding the better translator :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\def\temp#1#2{\def#1{\PauseMathClass{\HCode{<mi mathvariant="normal">}\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}x#2{59}}x\HCode{</mi>}}\EndPauseMathClass}}
\temp\Psi{03A8}
\temp\Delta{0394}
\temp\Xi{039E}
\temp\Pi{03A0}
\temp\Sigma{03A3}
\temp\Upsilon{03A5}
\temp\Omega{03A9}
\EndPreamble
```

It redefines `\Psi` and other problematic programs to output `<mi mathvariant="normal">Ψ</mi>`. The `mathvariant="normal"` attribute is necessary in order to display Psi as upright text. TeX4ht produces by default just `<mi>` element, without this attribute. `<mi>` elements that contain just single letter are displayed in italics by MathML, so it is necessary to use the mathvariant attribute. The `\special` command uses TeX4ht DVI processing instructions to output Unicode codepoint of Psi. `\PauseMathClass` disables the normal TeX4ht font processing, we need this in order to prevent some additional tags be written.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Great, gets me closer to the solution. Putting your text (with added closing }) into test.cfg and running ```make4ht test 'test,mathml,mathjax'``` gives in the output something like ```<mi mathvariant="normal"><mi 
>&#x03A8;</mi></mi>```. If it is compiled _only_ with mathml then firefox dsiplays it correctly. MathJax fails -- the 'inside' ```<mi>``` misleds it. Any way to prevent the double `<mi>` tag?

Comment: @Fedxa you are right, I've posted an updated cfg file that should work better and also support other simillar commands.

Comment: Great! That one reproduces properly the original TeX formatting. Do you think it should make it to the default mathml.ht4? I agree, that upright caputal greek fonts is a legacy, but consistency of formatting is probably more important...

Comment: Ups, the updated file fails on `$\Psi_x$`... Produces `<mi mathvariant="normal"><msub><mrow 
>&#x03A8;</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mi 
>x</mi></mrow></msub 
>`

Comment: Oh, adding an extra pair of '{}' in the def command made the code robust. Will add the fully working solution to my post later today. Thank you @michal.h21 !

Comment: @Fedxa I've already added it to the default `mathml.4ht`. You are right about the subscripts issue and that extra braces fixes that. I will update the sources with this addition.

Comment: @Fedxa this method with extra group works also for `\mathrm` etc., which was a long-standing issue. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: Excellent. I was suspecting this is the same problem, good that this hint can solve it globally. query-replacing through my files to catch bad subscripts was quite tedious.

Comment: @Fedxa for example `\mathit{hello}^2` works now. There is still issue with `x^\mathit{xxx}`, it results in compilation error. But it is definitely wrong TeX code, so I don't even know if it is possible to fix that on TeX level. It is always possible to preprocess the input and fix it using some command line scripts, like here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#x4-180003.2.3